# How do I add another tab using CSS3?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I found an example of CSS tabs [here](http://csscience.com/css3-tabs/);
I am using the third example "target".  However, when I attempted to add a FOURTH tab, everything breaks down, even with the first 3 (working) tabs.  My attempt is [here](http://soflorealty.com/tabs2/index.htm);

I believe the following original CSS codes need to be adjusted, which I do not know how to make sense of;

```
/* Target Tabs */
.tabs-target span:nth-of-type(1):not(:target) ~ span:nth-of-type(2):not(:target) ~ .tab:nth-of-type(1),
.tabs-target span:nth-of-type(2):target ~ .tab:nth-of-type(2),
.tabs-target span:nth-of-type(1):target ~ .tab:nth-of-type(3)
{
  display: block;
}
```

**What do I need to adjust to get the FOURTH tab to function properly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
.tabs-target span:nth-of-type(1):not(:target) ~ span:nth-of-type(2):not(:target) ~ span:nth-of-type(3):not(:target) ~ span:nth-of-type(4):not(:target) ~ .tab:nth-of-type(1),
 .tabs-target span:nth-of-type(4):target ~ .tab:nth-of-type(1),
 .tabs-target span:nth-of-type(3):target ~ .tab:nth-of-type(2),
 .tabs-target span:nth-of-type(2):target ~ .tab:nth-of-type(3),
 .tabs-target span:nth-of-type(1):target ~ .tab:nth-of-type(4) {
        display: block;
}
```

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pepD9/)

Answer (score 0):

By this you can add any number of tabs by just adding in html

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           Tab One
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

       <div class="content">
           Tab Two
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           Tab Three
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-4">Tab Four</label>

       <div class="content">
           Tab Four
       </div> 
   </div>


</div>
```

<-- to add more tabs just copy the .... fully and change its value accordingly. -->

CSS

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/mB56C/)